# Accessing HTTP Port (Port 80) command

Tags: xubuntu, https

How do I access an open HTTP port via command prompt?

For SSH I know it’s: ssh username@ipaddress 
And FTP: ftp *ip6 address*

I’m new to penetration testing so thought I’d ask.

Server is Apache2

Comment: You can try telnet command. telnet ipaddress/hostname port

Comment: `netcat` is a clean alternative for `telnet` (I seem to remember the author of `netcat` ranting about the protocol overhead of telnet).

Comment: Ok thanks. I’ve tried that but keep getting a response saying “connection closed by foreign host”